# Android mode doze não retorna app em background

Tags: android, background

estou com um problema que é o seguinte:
 Meu aplicativo envia as coordenadas de tempo em tempo(recebo esse intervalo do WebService). Mas o maior problema é quando o celular é desligado ou mesmo reiniciado o serviço não retorna em backgroud, alguem já passou por isso? como eu poderia resolver.

```
public class LembreDeMandarLocalizacao extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "enviarLocalizacao";
    public static final String ACTION = "com.routerbox.routerboxosoficial.LEMBRE_DE_MANDAR_LOCALIZACAO";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Enviou dados do dispositivo: " + new Date());
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MandarLocalizacaoService.class));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MandarLocalizacaoService extends IntentService implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "enviarLocalizacao";
    private static final String CICLO_SERVICE = "cicloService";
    private ChaveIntegracao chaveIntegracaoClasse;
    private List<DadosDispositivo> dadosDispositivos;
    private NivelDeBateria nivelDeBateria;
    private String nivelBateria;
    private float nivelBateriaFloat;
    private NumberFormat format;
    private Intent intent;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String dataFormatada;
    private ConexaoComInternet conexaoComInternet = new ConexaoComInternet(this);
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private DadosDispositivoDAO dadosDispositivoDAO;
    private static final int CONSTANTE_PERMISSOES = 1;
    private SharedPreferencesClasse sharedPreferencesClasse = new SharedPreferencesClasse();

    public MandarLocalizacaoService() {
        super("nomeDaThreadAqui");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
        dadosDispositivoDAO = new DadosDispositivoDAO();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onCreate::MandarLocalizacaoService");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onStartCommand::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onBind::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        return super.onBind(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onUnbind::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onHandleIntent::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        enviarDados();
    }


    private void enviarDados() {
        try {
            // Simula algum processamento
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "enviarDados::MandarLocalizacaoService");
            iniciadorComponente();
            String urlBase = sharedPreferencesClasse.obterSharedPreferences(getBaseContext(), "urlBase");
            int idDispositivo = sharedPreferencesClasse.obterSharedPreferences(getBaseContext(), "idDispositivo", 1);
            String usuario = sharedPreferencesClasse.obterSharedPreferences(getBaseContext(), "usuario");

            format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
            nivelBateriaFloat = nivelDeBateria.verficaNivelBateria(getBaseContext());
            nivelBateriaFloat = nivelBateriaFloat * 100;
            Log.d(TAG, "Nível Bateria Float: " + nivelBateriaFloat);

            dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            Log.d(TAG, "Data formatada: " + dataFormatada);
            if (latitude > 0 && longitude > 0){

            }
             else  {
                try {
                    latitude = Double.parseDouble(sharedPreferencesClasse.obterSharedPreferences(this,"latitude"));
                    longitude = Double.parseDouble(sharedPreferencesClasse.obterSharedPreferences(this,"longitude"));
                }catch (NullPointerException e){

                }


            }

            if (conexaoComInternet.estaConectadoComAInternet()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "verifica registros: " + dadosDispositivoDAO.verificaSeExisteRegistros(databaseHelper));
                if (dadosDispositivoDAO.verificaSeExisteRegistros(databaseHelper)) {
                    Autenticacao autenticacao = new Autenticacao(chaveIntegracaoClasse.criarChaveIntegracao(sharedPreferencesClasse.obterSharedPreferences(getBaseContext(), "cnpjEmpresa")),usuario);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Lista de dados do dispositivo: " + dadosDispositivoDAO.listarDadosDispositivo(databaseHelper));
                    RecebeDadosDispositivo recebeDadosDispositivo = new RecebeDadosDispositivo(autenticacao, dadosDispositivoDAO.listarDadosDispositivo(databaseHelper));
                    EnvelopeLocalizacao envelopeLocalizacao = new EnvelopeLocalizacao(recebeDadosDispositivo);

                    //chama o retrofit para fazer a requisição no webservice
                    EnviarLocalizacaoCallback enviarLocalizacaoCallback = new EnviarLocalizacaoCallback(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            urlBase);
                    enviarLocalizacaoCallback.enviarDadosDispositivo(envelopeLocalizacao);
                    Log.d(TAG, "ExemploServico processando com internet, tem registros no banco");
                } else {
                    Autenticacao autenticacao = new Autenticacao(chaveIntegracaoClasse.criarChaveIntegracao(sharedPreferencesClasse.obterSharedPreferences(getBaseContext(), "cnpjEmpresa")),usuario);

                    dadosDispositivos.add(new DadosDispositivo(usuario, dataFormatada, String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude), String.valueOf(nivelBateriaFloat), String.valueOf(idDispositivo)));

                    RecebeDadosDispositivo recebeDadosDispositivo = new RecebeDadosDispositivo(autenticacao, dadosDispositivos);
                    EnvelopeLocalizacao envelopeLocalizacao = new EnvelopeLocalizacao(recebeDadosDispositivo);

                    //chama o retrofit para fazer a requisição no webservice
                    EnviarLocalizacaoCallback enviarLocalizacaoCallback = new EnviarLocalizacaoCallback(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            urlBase);
                    enviarLocalizacaoCallback.enviarDadosDispositivo(envelopeLocalizacao);
                    Log.d(TAG, "ExemploServico processando com internet, não tem registros no banco");
                }
            } else {
                dadosDispositivos.add(new DadosDispositivo(usuario, dataFormatada, String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude), String.valueOf(nivelBateriaFloat), String.valueOf(idDispositivo)));
                dadosDispositivoDAO.inserirDadosDispositivo(databaseHelper, dadosDispositivos);
                Log.d(TAG, "verifica registros: " + dadosDispositivoDAO.verificaSeExisteRegistros(databaseHelper));
                Log.d(TAG, "ExemploServico processando sem internet, salva registros no banco");
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(@Nullable Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onStart::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "stopService::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
//        stopLocationUpdates();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
        // Ao encerrar o serviço, altera a flag para a thread parar
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onDestroy::MandarLocalizacaoService");
    }

    private void iniciadorComponente() {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "iniciadorComponente::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        chaveIntegracaoClasse = new ChaveIntegracao();
        nivelDeBateria = new NivelDeBateria();
        dadosDispositivos = new ArrayList<>();
        intent = new Intent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onConnected::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onConnectionSuspended::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "startLocationUpdates::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates(){
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "stopLocationUpdates::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(CICLO_SERVICE, "onLocationChanged::MandarLocalizacaoService");
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d(TAG, "latitude: " + latitude);
        Log.d(TAG, "longitude: " + longitude);
        sharedPreferencesClasse.gravarSharedPreferences(this,"latitude", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        sharedPreferencesClasse.gravarSharedPreferences(this,"longitude", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

---

Aqui uso esse alarme para disparar de quanto em quanto tempo:

```
public class AlarmUtil {

    private static final String TAG = "enviarLocalizacao";

    // Agenda o alarme na data/hora informado.
    public static void schedule(Context context, Intent intent, long triggerAtMillis){
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarme.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarme agendado com sucesso.");
    }

    // Agendar o alarme com a opção de repetir
    public static void scheduleRepeat (Context context, Intent intent, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis){
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarme.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, pendingIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarme agendado com sucesso com repeat. ");
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarme agendado com sucesso triggerAtMillis (Agendar): " + triggerAtMillis);
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarme agendado com sucesso intervalMillis (Intervalo): " + intervalMillis);
    }

    // Cancela o alarme
    public static void cancel(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarme.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarme cancelado com sucesso.");
    }

    // Verifica se alarme está ativo
    public static boolean checkAlarm(Context context, Intent intent){
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        if (alarmUp) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Alarme está ativo.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Alarme não está ativo.");
        }
        return alarmUp;
    }
}
```

Na activity principal tenho esse metodo onde verifico meu alarme

```
private void verificaAlarme() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LembreDeMandarLocalizacao.ACTION);
    boolean verificaAlarme = AlarmUtil.checkAlarm(MenuActivity.this, intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Verifica alarme: " + verificaAlarme);
    if (!verificaAlarme) {
        // Agenda para repetir no horário que retornar o ws
        AlarmUtil.scheduleRepeat(MenuActivity.this, intent, getTime(), intervaloCoordenadas * 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo? Está utilizando `JobSchedule`?

Comment: Sim, @ValdeirPsr estou utilizando ele.

Comment: Se possível posta o código que você está utilizando para agendar o serviço.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, postei  o codigo, mas me confundi estou usando o JobSchedule para outra, quando meu app fica sem internet e quando a internet ela volta sincronizo os dados que foram modificados.